How to send a document using two confused couriers?
You stand at point $100$ on the real line. You have a document that must arrive at point $0$ as soon as possible. The only two couriers available to you are confused, and might walk backwards instead of forwards, as explained below.
You give each courier a copy of the document. Then, at each time-step, you tell each of them how many steps to advance, which may be any integer in $\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. Then, one of the following two things happens (where $s_A$ is the number you told courier $A$ and $s_B$ the number you told courier $B$):

Courier A moves $s_A$ steps forward (towards $0$) and courier B moves $s_B$ steps backward;
Courier A moves $s_A$ steps backward and courier B moves $s_B$ steps forward.

You do not know in advance which of these options will take place; it depends on the changing mood of the couriers.
Question: Can you ensure that at least one of the couriers eventually arrives at point $0$? If so, how much time-steps do you need for that, in the worst case?
Here is an example of how the game can unfold. The initial state is $(A=100, B=100)$. You send $(3,3)$; suppose option 1 happens, so A walks forward and B walks backward. Then the next state is $(A=97, B=103)$. At the next time-step, you send $(2,3)$. If option 1 happens, the next state is $(A=95, B=106)$; otherwise, the next state is $(A=99, B=100)$.
EDIT: to get the document delivered, it is sufficient that one of the couriers passes near point 0, even without stopping. So if the state is (1,1) and courier A moves 2 steps forward, you win.

What happens if Courier A is at 1 and moves 2 steps forward?  And what happens if after that Courier A moves 2 steps forward again?

Interesting.  It's not clear what "worst case" would look like.  Initially, I thought it might be "couriers agree to maximize the sum of their positions" but that doesn't work...just give the instruction $(1,3)$ repeatedly.  So maybe it's "nearer one to $0$ always retreats" ...maybe that bounds the distance between them?  How close to $0$ have you been able to guarantee a guy?

If I am reading the conditions correctly you can't guarantee delivery. The couriers might happen (or cooperate) always to choose that the one nearer $0$ moves away from $0$, If I'm right I'll post this as an answer.

@EthanBolker Augment that anti-strategy so that if the one closer to the origin is given $0$ steps to move, the other one moves away from the origin. Then I think it works.

@EthanBolker I don't think that works. Send $(2, 2)$ and then $(1, 3)$. The positions will be $(100, 100) \to (98, 102) \to (99, 99)$. Repeat until the message is delivered.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson In this case you still win (it is sufficient to pass through 0, even without stopping).

I believe that the following adversarial strategy by the couriers should prevent the message from arriving.
Clearly, there are only $16$ possible messages. Count the number of times a certain messages has been sent modulo $2$. If a message comes up twice, the second time around, do the opposite movement of the first time. This way, at any point in time, both couriers will have moved at most $4 \cdot (0 + 1 + 2 + 3) = 4 \cdot 6 = 24$ tiles forwards. This shows that the answer is negative for any starting tile $\geq 25$.

That's awesome!

You can tighten the bounds even more, if you choose some of the 16 to start with option 1 and some to start with option 2.

@frodoskywalker True. If you want, you can add a better bound as an edit suggestion.

@Smiley1000 I was going to, but wrote it as my own answer instead. I'm pretty sure that can still be improved upon though

Building on smiley1000's excellent solution, the messengers can maintain an even tighter region around their start point.
Smiley1000 has correctly pointed out that there are 16 total instructions we can give our messengers. If every time they receive a specific instruction they alternate the option they choose, then neither of them will stray more than 24 spaces in the direction of 0. If they choose their initial response to each instruction, we can reduce this to 7 spaces:



Instruction
Initial response
max(A)
max(B)




(0,0)
A
0
0


(0,1)
A
0
0


(0,2)
A
0
0


(0,3)
A
0
0


(1,0)
B
0
0


(1,1)
A
1
0


(1,2)
A
1
0


(1,3)
A
1
0


(2,0)
B
0
0


(2,1)
B
0
1


(2,2)
A
2
0


(2,3)
A
2
0


(3,0)
B
0
0


(3,1)
B
0
1


(3,2)
B
0
2


(3,3)
B
0
3



This table shows the instructions, the messenger who will move toward position 0 the first time this message is received, and the maximum distance each messenger can be moved toward zero by this message. The totals in each max() column are 7, indicating that this strategy defeats us if we start at any position greater than 7.

Interesting! Do you see a simple way to generalize this to the case that each possible message is in ${0,\ldots,k}$?

You can partition the set according to which messenger has the smaller instruction - have them step towards 0, then for the cases where the instructions are equal partition them such that both messengers take an equal number of steps forward/back from a single iteration of them all. For all k = 4n + 1 or k = 4n + 2 this will not split equally. I suspect, but do not know, that it will for all k = 4n + 3 and k = 4n.

Assuming we can always split the {n,n} instructions so that at worst one messenger will travel one step closer than the other on the initial set of instructions, the maximum distance we can guarantee moving these messengers towards 0 is going to be ceiling(kth triangular number/2) + ((k-1)th pyramidal number)

The {n,n} instructions can always be split that way, by pairing k with k-1, k-2 with k-3, and so forth.  Even better (when k≥4), one can consider every {n,n} instruction at once, and ensure than they do not move either messenger more than k steps toward 0.

I do beleive that there is no winning strategy.
After some thinking (and no good intuition) I tried to test my intuition against a small program in python.
The program is based on the following: you can compute the set of winning points iteratively:

from a position (x,y) if there is a play such that option 1 or 2 leads to a wining position then add (x,y) to the set of winning position

This is true since when the computation finished. If you are in a winning position you can play what allowed the position to be added to the winning set. This strategy gives you a startegy that decrease the rank of the position (where the rank is the iteration at which we aded the position).
Outside this set of wining positions, for any number you choose the courier can behave such that you stay outside the winning positions (by construction) thus they will never reach 0.
Assumming my programation is corect the set of position with a winning strategy is :
{(-11, 2), (4, 9), (1, -15), (1, -6), (11, -4), (-8, 1), (-4, -8), (-4, 1), (7, 1), (12, -3), (-12, -3), (4, -7), (-4, 10), (-11, 4), (4, 2), (1, -13), (3, 6), (8, 2), (0, -2), (0, -1), (11, -1), (11, -2), (-8, -6), (-8, 3), (15, -1), (-4, -6),
(7, -6), (-4, 3), (7, 3), (-11, -3), (-16, 1), (4, -5), (8, -5), (3, 8), (8, 4), (-5, 4), (0, 0), (-8, -4), (-8, 5), (-4, -4), (7, -4), (-4, 5), (7, 5), (-12, 1), (3, 1), (14, 1), (8, -3), (3, 10), (-5, 6), (0, 2), (11, 2), (-8, -1), (-8, -2), (-4, -11), (-4, -1), (-4, -2), (7, -1), (7, -2), (-4, 7), (4, -10), (7, 7), (-12, 3), (3, -6), (3, 3), (3, 12), (-5, 8), (11, 4), (-4, -9), (-16, -1), (2, 13), (-4, 9), (3, -4), (-5, -8), (3, 5), (-5, 1), (0, -3), (11, -3), (-8, 2), (10, 1), (-4, -7), (7, -7), (2, 6), (-4, 2), (7, 2), (-12, -1), (-12, -2), (3, -11), (3, -1), (3, -2), (14, -1), (-5, -6), (14, -2), (3, 7), (-5, 3), (-8, -5), (10, 3), (-4, -5), (7, -5), (2, 8), (-4, 4), (7, 4), (3, -9), (6, 8), (3, 0), (-5, -4), (-1, 13),
(3, 9), (-2, 13), (-5, 5), (10, -4), (2, 1), (-9, 1), (-4, -3), (7, -3), (2, 10), (-12, 2), (3, -7), (-1, 6), (-2, 6), (3, 2), (14, 2), (-5, -1), (-5, -2), (-1, 15), (3, 11), (-5, 7), (10, -1), (10, -2), (2, -6), (-4, -10), (2, 3), (-9, 3), (2,
12), (6, 3), (3, -5), (-1, 8), (-2, 8), (3, 4), (-5, -9), (-1, 17), (-5, 9), (2, -13), (2, -4), (-9, -4), (2, 5), (-9, 5), (-17, 1), (2, 14), (6, -4), (6, 5), (3, -12), (-1, 1), (-2, 1), (3, -3), (-13, 1), (-1, 10), (-2, 10), (-5, -7), (-5, 2),
(2, -11), (10, 2), (9, 4), (2, -1), (2, -2), (-9, -1), (-9, -2), (2, 7), (6, -1), (6, -2), (-1, -6), (-2, -6), (3, -10), (6, 7), (-1, 3), (-2, 3), (-5, -5), (-1, 12), (-2, 12), (17, 1), (9, -3), (2, -9), (5, 8), (10, 4), (-6, 8), (2, 0), (2, 9), (-1, -13), (-2, -13), (-1, -4), (-2, -4), (3, -8), (-1, 5), (-2, 5), (-10, 1), (-5, -3), (-1, 14), (-2, 14), (5, 1), (-6, 1), (10, -3), (2, -7), (-3, 6), (2, 2), (-9, 2), (-17, -1), (2, 11), (6, -7), (-1, -11), (-2, -11), (6, 2), (-1, -1), (-1, -2), (-2, -1), (-2, -2), (-13, -1), (-1, 7), (-2, 7), (1, 15), (-10, 3), (-13, -2), (-1, 16), (-6, -6), (5, 3), (-6, 3), (2, -14), (9, 1), (2, -5), (-9, -5), (-3, 8), (2, 4), (-9, 4), (13, 1), (6, -5), (1, 8), (-1, -9), (6, 4), (-2, -9), (-1, 0), (-2, 0), (1, 17), (-10, -4), (-1, 9), (-2, 9), (5, -4), (-6, -4), (17, -1), (5, 5), (-6, 5), (2, -12), (-3, 1), (9, 3), (2, -3), (-9, -3), (-14, 1), (-3, 10), (-1, -16), (6, -3), (-1, -7), (-2, -7), (1, 10), (6, 6), (-7, 6), (-2, 2), (-1, 2), (-13, 2), (-10, -1), (-10, -2), (-1, 11), (-2, 11), (5, -1), (-6, -1), (5, -2), (-6, -2), (-3, -6), (2, -10), (5, 7), (9, -4), (-3, 3), (-6, 7), (9, 5), (-3, 12), (1, 3), (-1, -14), (-2, -14), (16, 1), (-1, -5), (-2, -5), (1, 12), (-1, 4), (-2, 4), (5, -9), (-3, -4), (9, -1), (2, -8), (9, -2), (5, 9), (-3, 5), (4, 11), (1, -4), (13, -1), (13, -2), (6, -8), (1, 5), (-1, -12), (6, 1), (-7, 1), (-2, -12), (-1, -3), (-2, -3), (1, 14), (-10, 2), (5, -7), (-6, -7), (-3, -11), (-6, 2), (5, 2), (4, 4), (-3, -1), (-3, -2), (-14, -1), (-14, -2), (-3, 7), (1, -11), (1, -1), (1, -2), (6, -6), (-7, -6), (1, 7), (-1, -10), (-2, -10), (-7, 3), (1, 16), (-10, 4), (12, 1), (5, -5), (4, -3), (-6, -5), (-3, -9), (5, 4), (-6, 4), (4, 6), (-3, 0), (9, 2), (-3, 9), (1, -9), (8, 6), (1, 0), (13, 2), (-1, -17), (-7, -4), (16, -1), (-1, -8), (1, 9), (-2, -8), (-7, 5), (-15, 1), (-10, -3), (-11, 1), (12, 3), (5, -3), (-6, -3), (-3, -7), (9, -5), (5, 6), (-6, 6), (4, 8), (-3, 2), (1, -16), (-14, 2), (-3, 11), (1, -7), (1, 2), (-1, -15), (-7, -1), (-7, -2), (1, 11), (-7, 7), (4, -9), (4, -8), (-11, 3), (4, 1), (-3, -5), (4, 10), (-3, 4), (1, -14), (8, 1), (1, -5), (1, 4), (1, 13), (12, -1), (12, -2), (5, -8), (4, -6), (-6, -8), (-3, -12), (-4, 11), (-11, -4), (4, 3), (-3, -3), (8, -6), (1, -12), (8, 3), (1, -3), (-7, -7), (1, 6), (-7, 2), (-8, 4), (-15, -1), (-11, -1), (-11, -2), (5, -6), (4, -4), (-3, -10), (4, 5), (8, -4), (1, -10), (8, 5), (0, 1), (11, 1), (-7, -5), (-8, -3), (-7, 4), (-8, 6), (15, 1), (-4, 6), (7, 6), (12, 2), (4, -11), (4, -1), (4, -2), (-3, -8), (4, 7), (1, -17), (8, -1), (8, -2), (1, -8), (1, 1), (0, 3), (11, 3), (-7, -3), (-4, 8)}
The code:
play = []


for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        play += [(i,j)] 
        play += [(-i,-j)] 
        play += [(i,-j)] 
        play += [(-i,j)] 
  
winning_positions= set(play)

def sign(x):
    if x>0:
        return 1
    elif x<0:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

new = True
while new:
    new = False
    ng = set()
    for (a,b) in winning_positions:
        for (e,f) in play:
            (x,y)=(a+e,b+f)
            if sign(x)*sign(e) >0:
                valid = sign(y)*sign(f)<=0
            elif sign(x)*sign(e) <0:
                valid = sign(y)*sign(f)>=0
            else:
                valid = True
    
            if valid and x*y != 0:
                if not (x,y) in winning_positions:
                    if (a+2*e,b+2*f) in winning_positions:
                        ng.add((x,y))
                    if a+2*e==0:
                        ng.add((x,y))
                    if b+2*f==0:
                        ng.add((x,y))
            
    winning_positions=winning_positions.union(ng)
    new = (len(ng)>0)

print(winning_positions)```


I think you have a misunderestanding: it can only happen, that either $A$ steps forward and $B$ steps backward, or $A$ steps backward and $B$ steps forward. So in your four "play += ..." lines, two of them are not allowed.

Yes that what I understood and implemented. I check if the play is valid with the valid variable. This is a bit complicated to takle negative numbers. In my implementation either A or B step toward 0 (both can be incresing if one is negative)

OK, maybe I should read your code more carefully ^^ Another thing I notice is that there's an ambiguity in the original question: does it count as win, if one courier goes pass zero? E.g. moving from $2$ to $-1$. Anyway I think your approach is correct. +1

I assumed that only zero was winning. Passing zero only change the direction forward for me.

Note: The below answer assumes that "confused" couriers choose directions randomly.  Edit: See below.  This assumption is not necessary.

Question: Can you ensure that at least one of the couriers eventually
arrives at point 0.

Yes, almost surely (i.e., I mean almost surely in the mathematical/probabilistic sense).
At each time step, tell them to move 1 step.  Both couriers are now performing a one dimensional random walk, which will cross any arbitrary boundary,  (i.e., including starting point + 100) an infinite number of times.

If so, how much time-steps do you need for that, in the worst case?

The worst case is infinite.  As smiley1000 points out, any sequence can be infinitely repeated in both directions, thus blocking all progress (with my sequence, merely alternating directions is sufficient to trigger this issue).
Edit:
If the "confused" couriers are not random (or possibly are maliciously trying to defeat this algorithm), the above strategy will still work, but in that case it needs to be modified to randomly select 0 or 1 step.  This works because any ordering of arbitrary length n (e.g., 100 steps in the same direction) is a subset of some ordering of length m (where m is larger than n).  The previous setting is obviously false if the ordering permanently settles on one direction, but in that scenario the problem is trivially resolved.

I don't understand your edit. 100 steps in the same direction is a subset of some ordering, but that doesn't mean you'll actually end up 100 steps away (for example, if the ordering it's a subset of alternates steps in each direction).

The strategy doesn't work if the couriers are maliciously trying to defeat it. If a courier ever reaches point 1, he can simply choose to not take a step forward, and let the other courier do so. We'll never wind up in a scenario where both couriers are at point 1, in the worst case the average position either doesn't change (if one moves 1 space forward and one moves 1 space backward), or moves backwards (if one moves 1 space backwards and one moves 0 spaces). Randomly selecting moves cannot help beat a malicious actor, they respond to the moves you make regardless of how you pick them.

@MartianInvader: My point was more that you don't have to worry that choosing 1s and 0s randomly will ever degrade towards an unreachable state.  That said, I'll acknowledge that my proof for that is poorly constructed (but I still have confidence in my conclusions).

@NuclearHoagie: I'm assuming that the couriers are forced to decide their direction independently of being told whether they should move 1 or 0 steps forward.  So they can select a "malicious" strategy in advance, but that strategy is a pre-selected ordering of steps based on previous game state.  Basically, I'm allowing the same sort of strategies permitted in evil king/jailor puzzles.
